# Lilypond Scheme Substitution function not using its arguments properly?

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I would like to create a Lilypond music function that allows me to express this MWE:

```
{ \override Score.SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/30) a b c }
```

as

```
\spn #1 #30 { a b c }
```

I tried with with this:

```
\version "2.22.1"

 spn =
#(define-music-function
  (beg end notes)
  (number? number? ly:music?)
  #{
 
 { \override Score.SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment #(cons beg end)) #notes }
    
  #})

\spn #1 #30 { a b c }

\relative c''
    { \override Score.SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/30) a b c }
```

which does not produces same output as the MWE.

I get `programming error: Unknown type predicate.`

I suspect I am expressing the `ly:make-moment` argument improperly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"unknown type predicate" would be an error with LilyPond's internals when typechecking the arguments of `ly:make-moment` because the complaint should be that the argument of `ly:make-moment` is not a rational number.  If this persists into the latest version, report a problem to the bug reporting list.

Of course your code also is faulty: you need to write `(/ beg end)` where you write `(cons beg end)` because the `1/30` you replace is not a LilyPond fraction `1/30` (which would be represented by `(1 . 30)` indeed) but a Scheme exact rational number `1/30`.  Fixing that will help with your problem.

But you should get a proper error message rather than LilyPond not being able to tell you what it is complaining about.